# Misunderstanding on JavaBeans naming convention for methods on OCA

Tags: java, naming-conventions, javabeans

We are currently having same tests for the OCA certificate and today we run into a minor an issue. 
I'll try to keep is short:

```
Which are methods using JavaBeans naming conventions for accessors and mutators?

(Choose all that apply)
A. public boolean getCanSwim() { return canSwim;}
B. public boolean canSwim() { return numberWings;}
C. public int getNumWings() { return numberWings;}
D. public int numWings() { return numberWings;}
E. public void setCanSwim(boolean b) { canSwim = b;}
```

The answers (as specified by the OCA SE 8) : **C** and **E**

Our discussion was on the point C:

public int **getNumWings**() { return **numberWings**;}

The point of my colleagues was that it is wrong due to the rule mentioned below. The method accessor must've been **getNumberWings** so the point **C** was wrong. I have attached the table of rules from the OCA, where it think the rule 5 is wrong. [PHOTO of Rules for JavaBeans naming convention on OCA SE 8 page 206](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eg1Re.png)

From my knowledge the name of the method doesn't have to respect the the property.
What are your thoughts on this?

---

OCA Oracle Certified Associate Java SE 8 Programmer I Study Guide Exam 1Z0-808

I tried to find a proper answer also on:

JavaBeans conventions from oracle: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/beans.101.pdf?AuthParam=1484818426_7e07f5a35c14ebfbadb2c68798198d7e

JavaBeans Conventions (Java in a Nutshell)

Comment: If `numberWings` is private, then it doesn't actually matter what its name is.

Comment: I also added the table of roles

Comment: Thanks, I just run into the same issue myself and had the same questions. Nice to know that I'm not the only one got confused..

Comment: (A) is should be `isCanSwim()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your colleague is (I think) arguing that

```
public int getNumWings() { return numberWings;}
```

violates the JavaBean because the field name and the property name are different.

That is not supported by the spec.  The Java beans conventions (as codified [here](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch06_02.htm)) state:

> ## 6.2.2. Properties
>
> A bean defines a property `p` of type `T` if it has accessor methods that
>   follow these patterns (if `T` is boolean, a special form of getter
>   method is allowed):
>
> ### Getter
>
> ```
>     public T getP()
> ```
>
> ### Boolean getter
>
> ```
>     public boolean isP()
> ```
>
> ### Setter
>
> ```
>     public void setP(T)
> ```
>
> ### Exceptions
>
> Property accessor methods can throw any type of checked or unchecked exceptions

Note that it does not say anything about the name of the (typically) `private` field that holds the value of the property.   Indeed, the field may not even exist ... if the property value can be represented some other way.

Comment: On the OCA Course is a table of rules for naming convention, I think the rule 5 is not correct

Comment: Actually, it is fine.  Once again, you are confusing **property** and **field**.  Read the actual words that they used.

Answer (score 0):

In relation to the OCA, JavaBean rules are:

All class properties ie instance variables that have getters and setters should follow the following rules:

1) The instance variables are always set to private:

`private boolean happy;`

`private String name;`

2) The mutator/setter method's identifier for the property should always start with 'set' followed by the property's identifier with it's first letter uppercased:

`public void setHappy(boolean happy){}`

`public void setName(String name){}`

3) The accessor/getter method's identifier for a boolean propery should always start with 'is' *or* 'get' followed by the property's  identifier with it's first letter uppercased:

`public boolean isHappy(){}` *or*

`public boolean getHappy(){}`

otherwise if the property is not a boolean then the accessor/getter method's identifier should always start with 'get' followed by the property's identifier with it's first letter uppercased:

`public String getName(){}`

4) One nuance to be aware of is if we have a Boolean wrapper property instead of a primitive boolean property:

`private Boolean happy;`

then the getter method's identifier always starts with 'get' followed by the property's identifier with it's first letter uppercased, and *never* 'is' as we are returning an object and not a primitive value:

`public Boolean isHappy(){}`

5) The above rules only apply to the properties and their associated getter and setter method identifiers and not to any local variables of the methods including the method parameters.